Handle dynamic UI-ID in playwright with locator method?
Trying to select a button with dynamic UI-ID.
await page.locator('#ui-id-4').getByLabel('Add').click(); 
await page.locator('#ui-id-5').getByLabel('Add').click();

Does anyone have a good practice for this? Trying to find suggestions on the official playwright documentation without any good examples.

This is a possible XY problem because CSS selectors are discouraged anyway. So the "good practice" from the docs is don't select by id or CSS selectors in the first place. Can you provide more context, please (sample page, full code, high-level goal)? Thanks.

You may try using ^=, which is starts with in CSS, and then access required element by nth.
await page.locator("[id^='ui-id-']").nth(YOUR_INDEX).getByLabel('Add').click(); 


Worked! Thanks.

Then mark it solved and close ;)
